# iOS App is crashing after allowing Notification Permission on Release Build (In Debug Mode, Everything is working fine)

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, release

I am facing crash on my iOS App. When I install the library: @react-native-firebase/messaging, In debug mode, everything is working fine. But When I install the app in release mode on any iOS device, after opening the app, it goes crash.

**My project dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "inversify": "^6.0.1",
    "mime": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.13",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-localize": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-material-ripple": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-navigation-bar-color": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^12.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rn-emoji-keyboard": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "socket.io-client": "2.4.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
```

**Pod file:**

````
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

use_modular_headers!

target 'BotPenguinReactNativeMobile' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    #:flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

**Run in Release Mode in XCode:**
It through the exception on App Start:

Exception   NSException *   "-[GUL_AppDelegate-57E40680-A962-46D9-8F1B-8F443EF66362 application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28362e880" 0x0000000282d1af70

AppDelegate:

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <Firebase.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  self.moduleName = @"BotPenguinReactNativeMobile";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

// Explicitly define remote notification delegates to ensure compatibility with some third-party libraries
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  return [super application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

// Explicitly define remote notification delegates to ensure compatibility with some third-party libraries
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  return [super application:application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

// Explicitly define remote notification delegates to ensure compatibility with some third-party libraries
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  return [super application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
@end
```

Comment: it's hard to tell without the crash log

Comment: Showing the pod file and the dependencies is pointless. You need to narrow down where the problem is occurring, have you tried to run the app in release mode using Xcode?